# Why does Spotify take control of my Bluetooth earphones' stereo output?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth, spotify

I own Bluetooth earphones, which I have paired with my Windows 10 laptop.

I can happily listen to audio from various different sources, until I play music through Spotify. Once I do, Spotify seems to completely hijack the stereo output device. If I pause the music and attempt to listen to another source (such as YouTube), I can no longer hear the audio playback despite seeing the amplitude bar move in the Windows sound settings. However, if I resume the Spotify music whilst the other sound source is still outputting, I can hear the other sound in the background of Spotify's output. Without restarting the earphones, I have found two ways of restoring the ability for other applications to output sound:

- If I right click on the earphones' Hands-Free device in the Windows playback device list and select "Test", I briefly hear the test output via the Hands-Free device and then suddenly the stereo output from the non-Spotify application continues.
- If I close Spotify whilst music is playing (and so the other app's audio can be heard in the background), the audio from the non-Spotify application can be heard again. However, if I close it whilst Spotify is paused, the non-Spotify audio does not resume.

I've [found a hotfix](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Spotify-mutes-all-sound-after-pressing-pause/td-p/4512212) in which disabling "Show desktop overlay when using media keys" from the Spotify settings prevents this issue from occuring, but what is causing this strange behaviour?

Note: I've disabled the ability for applications to take exclusive control of both the "Stereo" and "Hands-Free" playback devices for my earphones, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be because you have the earphones set as Default Output in the windows sound mixer, and Spotify 'just' chooses to play there - given no other choice.
Could you go into the Windows Sound Mixer, either via right click on the sound icon in your task bar and select 'Open Sound Settings' or via Settings - System - Sound - App Volume and Device Preferences.
There you might be able to decide to what output Spotify is to play.
Also note that you can have different volumes for different outputs.
See in Volume Mixer.